# setState(null) in jgroups

Tags: jgroups

I'm using jgroups 2.12.1 to keep in sync a table of session between different instances of an application.

I'm using the default UDP configuration.

Here is an extract of the SessionTable class, that implements (among others) the MessageListener interface.

```
@Override
public byte[] getState() {
    try {
        synchronized(this) {
            return Util.objectToByteBuffer(idMap);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Exception in getState()", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void setState(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        synchronized(this) {
            idMap = (Map<Long,SessionDescriptor>)Util.objectFromByteBuffer(bytes);
            userMap.clear();
            for (SessionDescriptor desc: idMap.values()) {
                userMap.put(desc.getUser(), desc);
            }
        }
        LOG.info("Session table retrieved from group: "
                + idMap.size() + " sessions " + bytes.length + " bytes");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Exception in setState()", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have recently discovered that in some cases, a setState is broadcast with a null argument:

```
....jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER;discovered that the state provider (radius-ext-gv2-39388) crashed; will return null state to application
```

I has worked as is for 6 or 7 years without problem, and twice this month the session table was set to null, resulting in NPEs all over the place.

So I was wondering what would be the best way to deal with nulls passed to setState. I can think of at least three strategies:

1. keep the table unchanged,
2. reset the table,
3. set a flag, and next time a setState is invoke with a non-null parameter, merge the two tables.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At least in later versions, JChannel.getState() throws an exception when the state provider (usually the coordinator) crashed during state transfer. I would simply call JChannel.getState() again, perhaps after a little sleep, because this will then access a different state provider (the new coord).